# estructuras unidimensionales en c++

Tags: c++

Necesito crear un método que cambie las posiciones de los vectores por ejemplo si el vector tiene tamaño 4, entonces el digito que esta en esa posición se cambie a la posición 0 y asi con todos. O sea que al final queden intercambiados de posición nada más.

```
int intercambio(int auxiliar){
        for (int  vector[i]= auxiliar; i<cantidad; i++){
            for(int vector[j] = vector[i]; j<cantidad; j--){
                vector[j]=auxiliar;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: si quieres intercambiar el valor de la posición 3 con la posición 0, usa [`std::swap`](https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap): `std::swap(vector[3], vector[0]);`.

Comment: si tienes un vector de tamaño 4, el digito de esa posicion no existe (ya que solo tienes 0,1,2,3).  y cambias el de esa posicion al de 0 y con el resto... que quieres hacer? pasarlos tambien a la posicion 0 ? Por favor, intenta explicar mejor el problema, ok?